# Prove that the following sum converges

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation

I'm supposed to determine whether this sum converges but I was unable to solve it by using any of the tools I've been taught. I have tried the integral test (which yielded a non-elementary solution), I have tried the root test, and I have tried the ratio test. It's really simple but I've been unable to solve it. I will appreciate any help.

The result I'm supposed to get is that it diverges (which does not seem right to me).

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\arctan(n)}{n}$$

Comment: $\arctan x + \arctan \frac 1 x = \frac \pi 2$ for $x>0$...

Comment: @StefanLafon Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I don't see why this is relevant.

Comment: Can you use this to estimate the magnitude of $\arctan n$ as $n\rightarrow+\infty$?

Comment: $\arctan(n) > 1$ for some $n > N$. Hence your sum is larger than $\sum 1/n$, which is divergent.

Comment: @StefanLafon Yes, the limit of arctan(n) is $\frac{\pi}{2}$, but I don't see how that is helping me as the n in the denominator is dragging the value towards zero.

Comment: Exactly, so the limit of $\arctan n$ is $\frac \pi 2$ so the terms behave $\frac \pi {2n}$.

Comment: From $\lim_{n\to\infty}\arctan(n)=\frac\pi2$, you conclude "harmonic" divergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $n\in\Bbb N$,$$\frac{\frac{\arctan n}{n}}{\frac1n}=\arctan(n)\geqslant\arctan(1)=\frac\pi4.$$So, since the harmonic series diverges, your series diverges too.

Answer (score 0):

We have :
$$\dfrac{\arctan n}{n} \sim \dfrac{\pi}{2n}$$
and the harmonic series :
$$\sum \dfrac{1}{n}$$
diverge then the series :
$$\sum \dfrac{\arctan n}{n}$$
diverges too.